# WPF, Mahapps, ThemeManager, how to convert ''Accent" into "ColorHex"?

Tags: wpf, colors, mahapps.metro

I'd like to get `System.Windows.Media.Color` from `MahApps.Metro.Accent`. To achieve this, I tried:

```
MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current,
                         MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.GetAccent("Green"),
                         MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseLight"));

// var == Tuple<MahApps.Metro.AppTheme, MahApps.Metro.Accent>
var AppStyle = MahApps.Metro.ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current);
Color CurrentColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(AppStyle.Item2.Name);
```

Then the actual hex color of `MahApps.Metro.Accent` for `'Green'` is `#FF548E17` but the hex color of `CurrentColor` is `#FF008000`. Is there any method to get `#FF548E17` in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the color from any accent resource with

```
// <Color x:Key="AccentColor">#CC60A917</Color>
Color accentColor = (Color)ThemeManager.GetAccent("Green").Resources["AccentColor"];
```

The same if you want to know the current selected accent color

```
Color currentAccentColor = (Color)ThemeManager.DetectAppStyle(Application.Current).Item2.Resources["AccentColor"];
```

Hope this helps!